# How do I make this not repeat the same thing

Tags: kotlin

I need this to print for each flight a number of "#" but its repeating it and  I can´t fix it.
This is the current output:

> TP23       ##############################
>
> TP23       #########
>
> TP1971     ############
>
> VN453      #####
>
> TP23       ##############################
>
> TP23       #########
>
> TP1971     ############
>
> TP23       ##############################
>
> TP23       #########
>
> VN453      #####
>
> TP1971     ############

This is the expected output:

> TP23       ##############################
>
> TP23       #########
>
> TP1971     ############
>
> VN453      #####

```
fun mapReservas(reservas: List<Reservas>): Map<Pair<String, Int>, List<Reservas>> {
    val map = mutableMapOf<Pair<String, Int>, MutableList<Reservas>>()
    for (reserva in reservas) {
        val key = reserva.numVoo to reserva.day
        val list = map[key] ?: mutableListOf()
        list.add(reserva)
        map[key] = list
    }
    return map
}


fun analiseEconomica(reserves: List<Reserves>) {
    val map = mapReserves(reserves)
    for (reserve in reserves) {
        map.forEach {
            val reservesNum = it.key.first
            val reservesDay = it.key.second
            val reservesCount = it.value.count()
            if (reservesNum == reserva.numFLight) {
                val conversion : Double = reservasCount * 1.5
                conversion!!.toInt()
                var count = 0
                val space = 10 - reservesNum.length
                print("$reservesNum")
                for (i in 0..space) {
                    print(" ")
                }
                while (count < conversion) {
                    print("#")
                    count++
                }
                println()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looping over `reserves` *and* the map you create. Drop the `for` loop and it should print the contents of the map only.

```
fun analiseEconomica(reserves: List<Reserves>) {
    val map = mapReserves(reserves)
    map.forEach {
       // Same logic here
    }
}
```

By having that extra for loop, you are saying you want to print out each of the values in the `map` once for each `Reserves` object in the list, that's why you get so many repeats.

FYI, there are more idiomatic ways to do what you are doing, but in the interest of answering your question directly I will leave it at this.

Comment: I have tried that but then reserve.numFlight doesn´t work because there is no reserve. @Todd